# Should we merge the mail tag with the email tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

While both tags are popular, I think we should merge [mail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mail) and [email](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/email) since you can't send a real mail in ubuntu and most questions using [mail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mail) are often problems in sending or receiving email.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed. Theoretically there might be questions about how to order Ubuntu installation media by postal mail, but since most questions about [mail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mail) are about [email](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/email), I think [mail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mail) should be made a synonym of [email](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/email).

Answer (score 1):

`Mail` tag can be used, but now it's widely used wrong.

Perhaps a better description to the `mail` tag will do the trick.

How do you make the tag code?

Comment: You can edit the mail tag wiki [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mail).

Comment: Thanks, I have added a tag wiki for mail. It's awaiting approval.

Comment: @user66987 You can make insert a reference to a tag using `[tag:mail]` which will print [tag:mail] (looks different in question/answer posts)